# django list folder fail

Tags: django, list, directory

I would like to list a folder (project folder/media/pictures/*)

I try that, but it fails (urls error I don't know why)

### Models

```
class Picture(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to="pictures")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file

    def getFileName(self):
        return self.docfile.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-new', )
```

### Urls

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from fileupload.views import PictureCreateView, PictureDeleteView

urlpatterns = patterns('fileupload.views',
    (r'^new/$', PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new'),
    #BUG BUG
    #(r'^list/$', gallery),
    (r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PictureDeleteView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-delete'),
)
```

### Views

```
def gallery(request):
    path="/media/pictures" 
    file_list =os.listdir(path)   
    return render_to_response('list.html', {'files': file_list})
```

---

---

Comment: Without the error message we can't help. Post the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gallery` should be a string:

```
(r'^list/$', 'gallery')
```